# Cannot access 'LoginPageModule' before initialization ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to insert google login for my ionic 4 apps and i have a problem everytime i click login button it look like this[image: have a problem like this]

```
Cannot access 'LoginPageModule' before initialization
```

and my code from login.page.ts look like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage{

  displayName: any;
  email: any;
  familyName: any;
  givenName: any;
  userId: any;
  imageUrl: any;

  isLoggedIn:boolean = false;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public googlePlus: GooglePlus
  ) { }

  login() {
    this.googlePlus.login({})
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.displayName = res.displayName;
        this.email = res.email;
        this.familyName = res.familyName;
        this.givenName = res.givenName;
        this.userId = res.userId;
        this.imageUrl = res.imageUrl;
        this.isLoggedIn = true;
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  logout() {
    this.googlePlus.logout()
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.displayName = "";
        this.email = "";
        this.familyName = "";
        this.givenName = "";
        this.userId = "";
        this.imageUrl = "";

        this.isLoggedIn = false;
      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

i've tried different approach but still get this error, anyone knows how to solve it?

heres login.module.ts, i have not touch this before but LoginPageModule is here so the problem, is from here?

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { LoginPage } from './login.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Comment: What is the code that is executed when you click the login button ? You need to show more code.

Comment: actually, when i click login it'll redirected to login.page.html where the google login button is place. but when accessing login.page.html the "Cannot access 'LoginPageModule' before initialization" error appear

Comment: recently i try to comment public googlePlus : GooglePlus, i can access login.page.html and the error is gone, but i don't actually know why it happens

Comment: Can you share the login.page.module.ts? was it working correctly before?

Comment: yeah, take a look again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Ionic 4, you have to add `/ngx` to your import directory string. The correct import will be -

login.page.ts

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';
```

And also you need to add GooglePlus to your module providers like this -

login.module.ts

```
...
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [LoginPage],
  providers: [GooglePlus]
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
```

Comment: but when i use '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';, ionic can't find that module so there's another error appear

Comment: i fixed that error by using this command npm install @ionic-native/google-plus@5.0.0-beta.14 and now i can use /ngx for my apps, but i'm facing with new error now LOL